# How to sort file after text-me-not/ in Unix and ignore case?

Tags: sort

I have this data and want to sort it alphabetically after the string `test-me-not/` and ignore case.

```
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/watermelon-green
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/orange-orange
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/apple-red
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/mango-yellow
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/Apple-green
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/Pineapple-yellow
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/cherry-red
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/grape-violet
hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/Grape-green
```

Comment: Since the prefix `hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/` is lexically identical in every case, it shouldn't matter whether you include or exclude it from the sort key

Answer (score 0):

**I assume that the data is in a file.**. (If not edit the question.)
Run in terminal:

```
cat /path/to/src/file | sed 's:hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/::' | sed '/^$/d' | sort  --ignore-case
```

for output in terminal and

```
cat /path/to/src/file | sed 's:hello-yourself/www/test-me-not/::' | sed '/^$/d' | sort  --ignore-case > /path/to/destination/file
```

for output in a file.

Answer (score 0):

To merge text files, then sort them line by line using this command on terminal:

```
cat textfile1.txt textfile2.txt | sort > sortedtextfile.txt
```

You can [watch this video](https://youtu.be/f8UJXdgaK2Q?t=133) for more context on this process.